# Why echo a backticks-row?

Tags: bash, backticks

I "inherited" some code in a project, and in one of the Bash scripts, they use `echo` on a backticks-row, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `/path/command argument`
```

What's the difference between that and just running the command itself?

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/command argument
```

Both send the command's output to the script's stdout.

So what's the difference? Why use `echo`?

To combine it with a `>` seems even worse:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `/path/command argument > /var/log/exemple.log`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look particularly useful in its current form but one side-effect of using `echo` with (unquoted) backticks is that whitespace between words is lost. This is because of word splitting - every word in the output of the command is treated as a separate argument to `echo`, which just outputs them separated by a single space. For example:

```
$ echo "a   b c"
a   b c
$ echo `echo "a   b c"`
a b c
```

Note that this applies to **all** types of whitespace such as tab characters and newlines.

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this deliberately! Personally, I'd be tempted to just run the command normally.

Comment: It also changes newlines to spaces.

Comment: Yes, can be something about whitespace, putting `echo "a" | grep "b` in echo-bacticks makes an empty row, insted of zero rows, and putting `echo -e "hi\nhi"` in echo-bacticks makes one row instead of two

Comment: The [useless use of `echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is a common, well-established antipattern.  If a programmer is doing it on purpose, I would expect a comment to explain how this is not the common antipattern.